# проблема с кодировкой maven project

Tags: java, maven, utf-8, кодировка, resourcebundle

я столкнулся со следующей проблемой: у меня имеется maven проект, и в моем проекте я использую ResourceBundel, который в свою очередь работает с Японскими символами. Проблема заключается в том, что когда я запускаю тесты, все отрабатывает корректно, кодировка при получении японских символов правильная. Но когда я выполняю maven clean package: в моих тестах, а так же и в функционале вместо японских символов ставятся "?". Я пробовал

```
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

для меня это не работает! В IDEA настройки: File encodings->Gefault encodings for property files UTF-8. 
Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <encoding>${encoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin> попробуйте добавить.

Comment: к сожалению тоже самое

Comment: Если у вас в surefire есть "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8", значит и тесты в идее надо запускать с таким же параметром.

Comment: тесты проходят, этот параметр я начал добавил в процессе борьбы со своей проблемой